# How can I add my service into remote app and start it which I injected by Xposed?

Tags: android, hook, inject, xposed

I recently hooked an app, and I've found some methods that I can call them in it, like I hooked a before onCreate method in the main activity, then I can call some method as well. That's perfect.

But I want to call them directly via my app, I can do it through BroadCast, but the broadcast can't run more than 10 seconds, it's very bad run some big task, and sometimes I prefer a result can be returned.

So seems it's wonderful I can add my service in the remote app and start it, but the problem is it isn't in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

By the way, how can I get the ClassLoader from the remote app, I am not sure it will be working if I got the ClassLoader.

Welcome to correct me!
Thank you all. Waiting for your opinions.
Feel free to contact me with email shiqwang@gmail.com or Wechat(id:imwangshiqi)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add my service into remote app and start it which I injected
>   by Xposed?

**Short answer:** You cannot start a service without registering it in the 3rd party app manifest. While with Xposed you could likely modify this behavior, it is likely a bad idea, not only because you would be messing with Android internals but also because there are easier alternatives to perform "remote invocations".

**Long answer:** If i understood correctly you want to build your own application that is able to control other Android applications hooked via Xposed.

If such is the case, understand that both apps will be completely isolated (different VM), you cannot simply pass an object from the 3rd party app (i.e., hooked app) to your app and expect any invocations on this object to be performed on the 3rd party app. You should check [Remote Method Invocation (RMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) to understand these concepts. This answers your question regarding the class loader.

Nonetheless, if all you want is to invoke one method of yours remotely on that app, then you can surely do that. As you mentioned you cannot launch a service in a 3rd party app if it is not specified in its manifest (well at least not without major hacking). But if you launch the service in your app, you can force the 3rd party app to bind to it, and implement message handlers that invoke your methods on the 3rd party app (via IPC).

In fact I have done so before using the Android Messenger for performing this communication ([i have written a detailed post on it](http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2014/02/21/how-to-do-android-ipc-using-messenger-to-a-remote-service/)). You will need to hook the app Activities (and other starting points as well if you want, e.g., broadcast receivers) to bind to the remote service. Then the service can send messages to to trigger actions on the hooked app.